# PHP - URL redirection weird behavior

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, redirect

I have a PHP code where i am showing a loading icon and then redirecting to URL 
lets say

**loadingIcon = "/src/images/load.png"**

**location = "default.html";**

The problem is, it **keeps showing the loading icon** on the page and won't proceed to the default.html redirection.

But if I replace the location to other like
location = "google.com"

It will show the loading icon and then go to google.com perfectly.

This basically tells that the problem is in default.html page but I tried opening the page locally, and it was working normally.

What could be the possible cause of this thing ?

Please suggest
Thank you in advance

Comment: We need a real code to help you :)

Comment: Provide some codes .

Comment: @Andurit I know buddy but I can't actually share the URLs...maybe I should put you similar dummy code...hold on

Comment: we don;t need URL, we want to see how you do things, so just source code not place wher it is running

Comment: @ajjay aroraa may be correct in one way. Try his solution.

Comment: Look at your Apache2 or PHPFPM logs ! :)

Comment: the location object here is javascripts Window Location obj.

@Ajjay thank you for the reply but i tried the thing you asked...it wont work

Can you suggest any other alternative for Window Location ??

Comment: can you paste your real code for redirect. Can you try `window.location = "default.html";` ?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
location = "default.html";
```

with

```
location = "yourdomain.com/pathtofile/default.html";
```

or

```
location = "../../default.html";
```

note: "../../" should be exact relative path to file.

Comment: I didn't work with PHP for a while but dont PHP `location` redirect user dispite the fact URL is invalid and apache will throw error 404?